# Java regular expression does not match

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract a string from a json object using regexs in java.

The string looks like this:

```
{"key":"value"}
```

The regex method code looks like this:

```
public String extractVal(String dataRaw) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(":\"(.+\b)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(dataRaw); //dataRaw is string from above^
    if (m.matches()) {
        return m.group(1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

It always just returns null. What did I do wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: why not simply using jsonparser or something

Comment: `I need to extract a string from a json object using regexs in java` ... no you don't, use a JSON parser instead.

Comment: I know what a JSON parser is, that's not what I asked.

Comment: Why do you `matches` and not `find`? Your regex obviously doesn't matches the whole JSON string.

Comment: Tried with find() and still did not work

Comment: And why do you play around with word boundaries instead of using the more obivous `":\"(.+)\""`? To support quotes in the String? Would `\b` support that? Would that happen?

Comment: `\b` should be `\\b` in Java string literal.

Comment: never mind, figured it out using http://txt2re.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your code

1. `\b` should be `\\b`
2. You should be using `find()` rather than `matches()`. The first will do a search on a given string and stops when it finds substring that matches the regex. Second will do a search on entire string. Because the provided regex doesn't match with the full string, the `matches()` does not work.

Simply fix your code on these two points, then it'll work. Tested myself.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer using text2re.com

```
public String extractVal(String dataRaw) {
    String re1=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re2="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   // Uninteresting: word
    String re3=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re4="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))"; // Word 1
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matc = patt.matcher(dataRaw);
    if (matc.find()) {
        return matc.group(1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Still unsure what i screwed up, though.

EDIT: better solution:

```
public String extractVal(String dataRaw) {
    String test = ".+:\"(.+)\"";
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(test,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matc = patt.matcher(dataRaw);
    if (matc.find()) {
        return matc.group(1);
    }
    return null;
}
```